# Suspected voting fraud by duplicate user profiles

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, voting-fraud, duplicate-accounts

I just encountered a user who asked a question a few days ago and got a handful of answers. But today, suddenly they updated their question and removed the acceptance from the answer, which they'd accepted earlier.

I visited their profile and found that most of their questions got down-votes from the community. Some time later I saw that suddenly all of their questions got up-votes and their reputation bumped up.

Does Stack Overflow try to identify such users/events? Because it looked like you can create another account and always up-vote all of your activity on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There's a good chance that the vote fraud script will detect this, but flag it anyway.

Comment: @apaul34208 That's good. Can you provide some information about `fraud script`, I am curious?

Comment: The specifics of the script are kept secret to keep users from working around it. To put it plainly: yes, there are some automated processes that are in place to detect suspicious behavior, but they're not perfect so when you see something, go ahead and flag it.

Comment: How relevant is the "duplcate user profiles" part of the title? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree with you partially. because user did have two profiles and used the one profile to improve other profile. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: But you didn't say that in the question. So maybe explain that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To answer your more general question, yes Stack Overflow and its moderators have the ability to sniff out users who create fake accounts to vote for themselves. In the most obvious cases of this, the site will automatically detect the fraudulent votes and invalidate them. For the more persistent ones, or folks who slip through the system, we have tools to detect their fraudulent voting. We deal with those people as they appear on our radar.

In this specific case, the asker of the question was a clear voting sock puppet of another user. However, none of the answers on that question were by accounts associated with that user, so them unaccepting your answer didn't directly benefit themselves. I've removed this and another sock puppet I found, suspended the main account, and blocked them from creating new accounts at their current location.

Thanks for pointing this out. If it helps you feel any better, you would have lost the points from the accept vote anyway when the sock puppet was eventually found and deleted.

Comment: Yes. The account is removed now. Thanks a lot. Can you provide some information on how to flag such users?

Comment: @abhishekbafna - If you see suspicious voting behavior for an account, and you think it's worth us acting on, cast a custom flag on one of their posts and explain what it is you saw and why you think we should look into this account. You might want to check that the system or moderators haven't already acted on the voting, because we handle a lot of these before the community notices.